# The maven assembly plugin is not using the finalName for installing with attach=true?

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have configured following assembly:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>${project.name}-test-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <finalName>${project.name}-test</finalName>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>src/assemble/test/distribution.properties</filter>
                        </filters>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assemble/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <attach>true</attach>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>${project.name}-prod-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        <finalName>${project.name}-prod</finalName>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>src/assemble/prod/distribution.properties</filter>
                        </filters>
                        <descriptors>
                            <descriptor>src/assemble/distribution.xml</descriptor>
                        </descriptors>
                        <attach>true</attach>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

This produced two zip-files:

- distribution-prod.zip
- distribution-test.zip

My expectation for the property **attach=true** is, that the two zip-files are installed with the name as given in property **finalName**.
But the result is, only one file is installed (attached) to the artifact.
The maven protocol is:

- distrib-0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
- distrib-0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip

The plugin is using the artifact-id instead of property finalName!
Is this a bug?

The last installation is overwriting the first one.
What can i do to install this two files with different names?

Thanks for your investigation.
Roland

Answer (score 19):

> The last installation is overwriting the first one. What can i do to install this two files with different names?

As expected (I don't know if this is a bug or not but that's how the assembly plugin works). To avoid this, you will have to set the `appendAssemblyId` properties to `true` and, to obtain an equivalent result, to change the `finalName` to `${project.name}` and the assemby `id` to `test` and `prod` (i.e. to use two assembly descriptors). Something like this:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>${project.name}-test-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
            <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
            <filters>
                <filter>src/assemble/test/distribution.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/assemble/distribution-test.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
          <id>${project.name}-prod-assembly</id>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>single</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <appendAssemblyId>true</appendAssemblyId>
            <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
            <filters>
              <filter>src/assemble/prod/distribution.properties</filter>
            </filters>
            <descriptors>
              <descriptor>src/assemble/distribution-prod.xml</descriptor>
            </descriptors>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Where `distribution-test.xml` and `distribution-prod.xml` declare assembly `id` `test` and `prod` respectively.

Comment: Worked like a charm (did not try the code, but the principle)